# browser.navigate().back(); is causing "document unloaded while waiting for result" error

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, protractor

**Hello,**
I've read all the questions/answers on the platforms, and none of them helped me to solve my issues, the thing is that I have the following test script:

```
it('Verify user sees the home page correctly when hitting back button', function () {
    browser.get('/flight/los-angeles/');
    expect(testUtils.getTextFromField(topSearchBarPage.airportDestLocator)).toContain("LAX");
    element.all(by.css(".day-droppable.ui-droppable")).get(30).click();
    element(by.css(".btn-primary")).click();
    browser.navigate().back();
    expect(browser.getTitle()).toMatch('page title');
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain("/flight/los-angeles/");
});
```

And then I'm getting this error:

```
UnknownError: javascript error: document unloaded while waiting for result
```

I can see (because I've placed an sleep) that right after executing the `navigate.back()` the test tries to reload the page, and when it tries to execute the expects, it throws the error.

This is how the app looks like after the navigate.

[image: reload]

I've posted the question in GitHub, and here are the most important information:

> I had removed that step (the navigate back) and the expect function works, I had placed a browser.sleep(5000) right after the navigate.back() and that's how I found that it's trying to execute the next "expecs" on an "empty page".

Then, sjelin, added this

> I'm pretty sure the issue is actually just that element(by.css(".btn-primary")).click(); hasn't finished before browser.navigate().back(); happens. Try adding a browser.waitForAngular()

And lastly I commented this.

> @sjelin I've tried what you told and it does not work, in fact, the clicking action does happens and finishes when it should since I'm seeing the action being done while the test runs... so, I think that the problem here is the navigate().back() is opening or refreshing without URL, and the next actions are the ones throwing the errors.

Comment: I've figured out that my problem is chrome! I've tried one of the suggestions against Firefox, and my test passes... would anybody have any workaround to suggest?

Answer (score 0):

What if you would explicitly wait for `click()` to finish:

```
element(by.css(".btn-primary")).click().then(function () {
    browser.navigate().back();

    expect(browser.getTitle()).toMatch('page title');
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain("/flight/los-angeles/");
});
```

Comment: I've even done what you suggested executing directly the javascript function, like this `browser.executeScript('window.history.back();');`